# Error " main.c:(.text+0x52): undefined reference to `salir' "

Tags: c, linux, gcc

Estoy aprendiendo a programar en C y estoy haciendo un programa con varios ficheros: main.c y commands.c y commands.h que están en diferentes directorios. Al intentar compilarlo me da el error:

/tmp/ccdrmrTI.o: In function `main': main.c:(.text+0x52): undefined reference to` salir'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

La función "salir" está implementada el fichero commands.c y declarada en commands.h. El fichero commands.h está incluido (#include) en el fichero main.c . De lo que dice el mensaje de error entiendo que he referenciado mal la función pero no entiendo por qué.

Aquí les pongo el codigo de los 3 ficheros:

Main.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "../incl/network.h"
#include "../incl/commands.h"

void imprimir_menu();
int preguntar_opcion(int min, int max, char mensaje[]);

int main (int argc, char *argv[]){

          {
          imprimir_menu();

          switch (preguntar_opcion(1,11, "Elija una opcion: ")){

              case 1:

              { salir();

              break;

              }

              case 2:

              break;
              
              case 3:

              break;

              case 4:

              break;

              default:

              printf ("Error, intente nuevamente");

          }
      } 

    return 0;
}

// Mostrar al usuario las opciones para gestionar la "base de datos"

void imprimir_menu() {
    printf ("[2022] SUCEM S.L. Recolector de redes inalambricas\n\n");
    printf ("  [ 1] wificollector_quit\n");
    printf ("  [ 2] wificollector_collect\n");
    printf ("  [ 3] wificollector_show_data_one_network\n");
    printf ("  [ 4] wificollector_select_best\n");
    printf ("  [ 5] wificollector_select_worst\n");
    printf ("  [ 6] wificollector_delete_net\n");
    printf ("  [ 7] wificollector_sort\n");
    printf ("  [ 8] wificollector_export\n");
    printf ("  [ 9] wificollector_import\n");
    printf ("  [10] wificollector_display\n");
    printf ("  [11] wificollector_display_all\n\n");
}

// Recibe el numero que representa la opcion elegida

int preguntar_opcion (int min, int max, char mensaje[]){
    int opcion;
    char opcionchar [SIZE];
    
    printf("%s", mensaje);

    do{
        scanf("%s", opcionchar);
        opcion= atoi(opcionchar);
        if ( opcion < min || opcion > max ) {printf("Por favor introduzca un numero entre %d-%d\n", min, max); }

    }while (opcion < min || opcion > max);

    return opcion;
    }
```

Commands.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "../incl/network.h"
#include "../incl/commands.h"

void salir() {

    char ch;

    printf("¿Esta seguro que desea salir del programa?");
    scanf("%c", &ch);
    if (ch == 's' || ch == 'S'){

        exit(0);
    } 

}
```

Commands.h

```
#ifndef _COMMANDS_H
#define _COMMANDS_H

void salir();

#endif
```

Alguien me puede ayudar?

Saludos,
Yal

Comment: ¿Cómo lo estás compilando? Es probable que hayas olvidado indicar el archivo `commands.c`. El comando debería ser más o menos así: `gcc main.c commands.c -o programa`

Comment: En efecto, sólo estaba compilando main.c ( gcc -Wal main.c). Por favor, pon tu solución como respuesta para poder marcarla como aceptada y así otros sepan que esa es la solución a este tipo de errores. Un saludo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recuerda indicar todos los archivos `.c` en la línea de comandos. Si te falta `commands.c` tendrás ese error.

Debería verse más o menos así:

```
 gcc main.c commands.c -o programa
```