# undefined reference to `Punto::getX(), POO en C++

Tags: c++, poo, objeto, clase

estoy aprendiendo POO en C++

Esta es la primera clase que he creado, lo único que tiene que hacer el programa es imprimir los valores de x e y.

Al compilar me da los siguientes errores:

*C:\Users\ikerc\AppData\Local\Temp\ccjrXvgQ.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x52): undefined reference to Punto::getX()'
C:\Users\ikerc\AppData\Local\Temp\ccjrXvgQ.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x96): undefined reference to Punto::getY()'*

Este es mi código original:

**Punto.h**

```
//Declaración de una clase

class Punto{
    //Atributos de la clase
    private: //Los atributos se encapsulan dentro de private
        int x, y;
    
    //Métodos
    public: //Todos los metodos acceden a este contenido
        Punto(int _x,int _y){ //Metodo constructor inicializa la clase
            x = _x;
            y = _y;
        }

        Punto(){ //Constructor 2
            x = y = 0;
        }

        void setX(int valorX); //Establecemos el valor de X
        void setY(int valorY); //Establecemos el valor de Y
        int getX(); //Obtener el valor de X
        int getY(); // Obtener el valor de Y
};
```

**Punto.cpp**

```
#include "Punto.h" //Indicar que vamos a utilizar el archivo

//Establecemos el valor de X
void Punto::setX(int valorX){ //Indicar Clase::metodo
    x = valorX;
} 
//Establecemos el valor de Y
void Punto::setY(int valorY){
    y = valorY;
} 
//Obtener el valor de X
int Punto::getX(){
    return x;
} 

// Obtener el valor de Y
int Punto::getY(){
    return y;
}
```

**main.cpp**

```
//Creacion de Objetos

#include<iostream>
#include "Punto.h"

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    Punto p1(2, 1); //Creación de un objeto estático
    
    cout<<"El valor de X es: "<<p1.getX()<<endl;
    cout<<"El valor de Y es: "<<p1.getY()<<endl;


    return 0;
}
```

Sin embargo, si defino los métodos dentro de **Punto.h** en ves de dentro de **Punto.cpp**, el programa sí funciona.

```
//Agregar al final de Punto.h
int Punto::getX(){
    return x;
}

int Punto::getY(){
    return y;
}
```

Quiero saber por qué aparece este error si defino `getX()` y `getY()` dentro de **Punto.cpp**, ya que tengo entendido que dentro de **Punto.h** sólo se deben poner los prototipos de los métodos, y posteriormente poner su definición en **Punto.cpp**

Comment: Bienvenido. ¿Cómo estás compilando el programa? ¿Con cual compilador? ¿Con qué línea de comandos? Posible duplicado: [Error " main.c:(.text+0x52): undefined reference to \`salir' "](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/558770/error-main-c-text0x52-undefined-reference-to-salir)

Comment: Por favor, **esto no es un foro**. Es contrario al sitio editar la pregunta para incluir en ella la solución. Si consideras que tienes algo que aportar nuevo/distinto, por favor, publica una respuesta. Un saludo.

Comment: Disculpas, es la primera vez que hago una pregunta, haré lo que me comentas.