# ¿Como soluciono "undefined reference to `function'?

Tags: c, gcc

Soy nuevo en C, y estoy tratando de compilar el siguiente código pero me aparece el error del titulo de esta publicación y `(main.c:(.text+0x79)) collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status`, he estado mirando otras publicaciones de este y otros sitios y la mayoría se refieren a que no se esta compilando y enlazando de la manera correcta o que la función esta siendo declarada de manera incorrecta, siempre he usado `C++` y `Genny Editor` para compilar, por tal motivo no se como compilar solo desde terminal, si tienen una publicación el la cual pueda aprender de esto seria de mucha ayuda. :)

> gcc main.c -o main.exe

Estructura proyecto

```
C
│
├── src
│   ├── main.c
│   └── IP2LOCATION-LITE-DB1.CSV
│
├── lib
│   ├── buscar.c
│   └── buscar.h
```

> main.c

```
#include "../lib/buscar.h"
int main(){

  printf("%s",RANGOS_IP);
  int n = contarFilas(RANGOS_IP);
  printf("%d",n);
  return 0;

 }
```

> buscar.h

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>

char RANGOS_IP[24] = "IP2LOCATION-LITE-DB1.csv";    
int contarFilas(char*);
```

> buscar.c

```
#include "buscar.h"
int contarFilas(char *nombreArchivo){...}
```

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Error " main.c:(.text+0x52): undefined reference to \`salir' "](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/558770/error-main-c-text0x52-undefined-reference-to-salir)

Comment: El linker no encuentra la función `contarFilas` porque está definida en el archivo `buscar.c`. Sin embargo no estás compilando el archivo `buscar.c` así que no tiene idea donde encontrarla. El comando sería `gcc main.c buscar.c -o main.exe`. [Hay una pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/65557/169744) más detallada al respecto. También te puedo sugerir [los videos de TheCherno](https://youtube.com/playlist?list=PLlrATfBNZ98dudnM48yfGUldqGD0S4FFb)

Comment: Y puede que este video te ayude https://youtu.be/tOQZlD-0Scc

Comment: @Mateo pero si ¿ buscar.c esta en otra carpeta como puedo hacerlo ? , y la serie de TheCherno no es para c, sino para c++ ?

Comment: Disculpa. Tienes que usar las rutas relativas a dónde estás ejecutando el compilador. Si estás posicionado en src, sería `../lib/buscar.c`. Respecto a la serie, si, es para C++ pero comparten mucho en común. Tranquilamente podrías mirar hasta el vídeo de punteros ya que luego aparecen videos sobre clases y otras cosas de C++. C no tiene clases ni referencias.

Answer (score 0):

Tu probelma esta en como compilas tu programa. Al hacer:

```
gcc main.c -o main.exe
```

Estas compilando tu programa `main.c` pero no `buscar.c`. Para solucionarlo simplemente compila de la siguiente manera:

```
gcc main.c buscar.c -o <NombreDelEjecutable>
```

### EJEMPLO:

main.c

```
#include "externo.h"

int main(){
    printf("Success!...\n");
    funcion_externa();
    return 1;
}
```

externo.h

```
void funcion_externa();
```

externo.c

```
#include <stdio.h>

void funcion_externa(){
    printf("Success(externa)!...");
}
```

Compilacion:

```
gcc main.c externo.c -o main
```

Output (`./main`):

```
Success!...
Success(externa)!...
```

### EDIT:

Respondiendo a tu comentario, el error que tenias

```
undefined reference to...
```

Es debido a que no agregas el archivo donde esta la definicion de la funcion a la compilacion. Para soluconarlo tienes que agregarlo a la forma en la que compilas.

`buscar.c` puede estar en mil lugares distintos, obviamente solo te puse una referencia, tienes que adaptarlo a tu proyecto por ejmplo atomatizando la cpmpilacion con un MAkefile. SI tiene sentido.
La estructura de tu proyecto es:

```
.
├── lib
│   ├── buscar.c
│   └── buscar.h
└── src
    └── main.c
```

Entonces, para compilar desde el directorio raiz de tu proyecto solo ajusta las rutas:

```
gcc src/main.c lib/buscar.c -o main
```

Comment: hay un error debido a que si buscar.c esta en un archivo diferente no tiene sentido

Comment: @josealejandrovaroncarreño "SI" tiene sentido. Tu error es en definitiva es que no agregas el archivo de la definicion a tu compilacion. Si los archivos estan en diferenets localizaciones obvio las rutas al archivo cambian. Solo adaptalo a tu proyecto. Me tome el tiempo de recrear la estrucrura de tu proyecto y compilar de manera exitosa. Saludos!